# Return after insert stored procedure, if success is return 1 else return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure. After insert, it should return a value: if the insert was successful, then return 1, else return 0.

For example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_save_transaction]
    -- Parameter
    @SourceCode nvarchar(255),
    @DepositorName nvarchar(255),
    @TransactionDate date
AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    --BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @PaymentDate date
    DECLARE @PaymentDepositorName nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @PaymentNationId int

    SET @PaymentDate = @TransactionDate
    SET @PaymentDepositorName = @DepositorName
    SET @PaymentNationId = (SELECT [NAT_SYS_ID] 
                            FROM [MB_TB_NATION] 
                            WHERE [NAT_CODE] = @DepositorCountry)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MB_TB_TRANSACTION]
           ([TRA_PAYMENT_DATE], [TRA_PAYMENT_DEPOSITOR_NAME], [TRA_PAYMENT_NATION_ID])
    VALUES (@PaymentDate, @PaymentDepositorName, @PaymentNationId, )
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use an output parameter.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by checking the "@@ERROR" attribute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx

Something along the lines of:

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN            
        RETURN 1;
    END;
```

However I'd consider using "0" as your success value, and anything else as an error. You can then use different values to represent different error states. Unless you're directly mapping the result to a boolean "success" value.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible solutions: the first one is based on output parameter, when you run it the parameter is valued with desired value.
The other solutions just return the desired result, as you were asking.
Both of them checks @@ERROR to know if last op succeeded or not.

Solution A:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_save_transaction]
    -- Parameter
    @SourceCode nvarchar(255),
    @DepositorName nvarchar(255),`enter code here`
    @TransactionDate date,
    @result int output
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

--BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @PaymentDate date
DECLARE @PaymentDepositorName nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @PaymentNationId int

SET @PaymentDate = @TransactionDate
SET @PaymentDepositorName = @DepositorName
SET @PaymentNationId = (SELECT [NAT_SYS_ID] FROM [MB_TB_NATION] WHERE [NAT_CODE] = @DepositorCountry)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MB_TB_TRANSACTION]
           ([TRA_PAYMENT_DATE]
           ,[TRA_PAYMENT_DEPOSITOR_NAME]
           ,[TRA_PAYMENT_NATION_ID]
           )
     VALUES
           (
           @PaymentDate, 
           @PaymentDepositorName, 
           @PaymentNationId, 
           )
  IF @@ERROR = 0 
     SET @result  = 1
  ELSE SET @result = 0
```

Solution B:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_save_transaction]
    -- Parameter
    @SourceCode nvarchar(255),
    @DepositorName nvarchar(255),`enter code here`
    @TransactionDate date
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

--BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @result int
DECLARE @PaymentDate date
DECLARE @PaymentDepositorName nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @PaymentNationId int

SET @PaymentDate = @TransactionDate
SET @PaymentDepositorName = @DepositorName
SET @PaymentNationId = (SELECT [NAT_SYS_ID] FROM [MB_TB_NATION] WHERE [NAT_CODE] = @DepositorCountry)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MB_TB_TRANSACTION]
           ([TRA_PAYMENT_DATE]
           ,[TRA_PAYMENT_DEPOSITOR_NAME]
           ,[TRA_PAYMENT_NATION_ID]
           )
     VALUES
           (
           @PaymentDate, 
           @PaymentDepositorName, 
           @PaymentNationId, 
           )
  IF @@ERROR = 0 
     SET @result  = 1
  ELSE SET @result = 0
RETURN @result
```